# How to calculate gradient color replacements?

Tags: css

I have the following CSS:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(#444f67, #262c39);
```

These are the start and end color of an existing gradient. Now I want to swop out the gradient, as I adjust the color scheme for this site.

I know the new start color:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(#542437, X);
```

How can I solve for X? based on....

```
oldStart -> oldEnd = ExistingGradient :: newStart -> X (new end) = NewGradient
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you want to base the new colour on? Same saturation and luminosity difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I usually solve this with pure CSS - use transparent gradient and only change the underlying background colour.

For example, instead of:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(#444f67, #262c39);
```

use:

```
background-color: #444f67;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.4));
```

Then you can swap the background colour another theme:

```
background-color: #542437;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.4));
```

Here's a working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/tukz3/).

---

Otherwise, if you're asking how to calculate the actual colour, you need to define your requirements. Do you want to do that server-side or client-side? It's fairly easy to do with C# and also possible to do with JavaScript.

Comment: I figured out - it is straight Hex addition / subtraction, but I like your solution for cleanness.